# My ANTLR4 listener produces correct dates but I am getting error output as well. Why?

Tags: c#, antlr4

Grammar is to parse the date string of MM/DD/YYYY format. Main function has three test strings, each one produces correct date but for the strings with 01 as DAY there is an warning or error output by antlr.

I am using antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar -Dlanguage=CSharp and Antlr4.Runtime.Standard 4.13.1

grammar:

```
grammar schedule;

date: MONTH '/' DAY '/' YEAR;

MONTH: '0' [1-9] | '1' [0-2];
DAY:   '0' [1-9] | [1-2] [0-9] | '3' [0-1];
YEAR: DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT;
DIGIT: [0-9];

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Listener class:

```
public class MyScheduleListener : scheduleBaseListener
{
    public override void EnterDate([NotNull] scheduleParser.DateContext context)
    {
        string dateText = context.GetText();
        Console.WriteLine("Found date: " + dateText);
    }
}
```

Main

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.Execute("01/01/2023");
        test.Execute("08/01/2023");
        test.Execute("12/26/2023");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void Execute(String input)
    {
        AntlrInputStream inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(input);
        scheduleLexer lexer = new scheduleLexer(inputStream);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        scheduleParser parser = new scheduleParser(tokens);

        scheduleParser.DateContext tree = parser.date();

        MyScheduleListener listener = new MyScheduleListener();
        ParseTreeWalker.Default.Walk(listener, tree);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
line 1:3 mismatched input '01' expecting DAY
Found date: 01/01/2023
line 1:3 mismatched input '01' expecting DAY
Found date: 08/01/2023
Found date: 12/26/2023
```

Comment: I mentioned this before. "01" is matched by both MONTH and DAY. If two rules match, the first one listed--MONTH--is returned. `date: MONTH '/' DAY '/' YEAR;` cannot match. The parser does not tell the lexer what to match. You should get in the habit of printing out the tokens returned by the lexer.

Comment: Thank you, kaby76, for the clarifications! I will try to find more info on these subjects

Comment: Tokens of the test 01/01/2023:
Token: 01 Type: MONTH
Token: / Type: '/'
Token: 01 Type: MONTH
Token: / Type: '/'
Token: 2023 Type: YEAR
Token: <EOF> Type: EOF